# Sorting HTML divs in front-end using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Consider the following `HTML` block representing a review of a product (content omitted for brevity):

```
<div class="reviews">
    <div class="review-item" id="someUniqueIdPerReviewItem">                    
        <div class="review-header">
            <div class="review-user">
            </div>                        
            <div class="review-date">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="review-info">
            <div class="review-rating">
            </div>
            <div class="review-message">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each product will have as many `"review-item"` divs in it's `"review"` div as it has reviews.

I'm returning this HTML in a `View` using `Razor` in `MVC`. I sort the reviews chronologically in the `Action` of the view's `Controller` prior to passing the reviews to my view.

Let's say that I want give the user the facility to order the reviews by other metrics, e.g. date ASC/DESC, rating ASC/DESC and so on. What is the most reliable way to do this in the frontend? Obviously, I would like to avoid making `AJAX` calls to the controller and passing a "sorting parameter" to rerender pretty much the exact same content in different order.

I'm already using `jQuery` to do some frontend calculations, animations etc but I'm a beginner in frontend development. I would guess that I could use jQuery to do something like this?

```
1. loop through every "review-item" in "reviews" and store it in a collection
2. sort the collection based on a particular property of "review-item"
3. clear the "reviews" div and append the collection to it
```

If not, what would be an appropriate way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: you tried looking at Angular's ng-repeat and using it's sorting algorithms for this?

Comment: @vimes1984 I would prefer avoiding adding additional JS libraries

Comment: Easy, just get the elements, sort them with `sort()`, and append them back again

Comment: @adeneo does `sort()` work for all sorts of types (e.g. in my case sorting dates or ratings) or does there need to be an explicit implementation for each type?

Comment: `sort()` has a callback function, inside that you can sort any way you want

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to use my [repeatable](https://github.com/c-smile/repeatable) jQuery plugin.

With it population of the list with ordering

```
var list = $("ul#people").repeatable(); // declaring the repeatable
    data.sort(sortFunction); // sort the data in the way you want
    list.value = data; // that's data population, sic!
```

Answer (score 0):

Theses might be helpful..

http://trentrichardson.com/2013/12/16/sort-dom-elements-jquery/
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

Thanks, Gareth